# Suggest Power law distributions reference

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What is everyone suggestion for a good Power Law Distribution reference in book or article form? Both theory and application is helpful (two separate books is fine).

Thank you.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96619/multivariate-power-law-distributions might help

Comment: Thank you, I didn't check mathoverflow.

Comment: You are very welcome! Regards